# How can I combine two mpeg2 clips into one output file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two movie clips encoded in mpeg2. Is it possible to use ffmpeg to combine them sequentially into one mpeg2 file? If so, what are the command line options?

Comment: And I'm not marking this as not-programming-related only because I've written a program to interface with ffmpeg. If this isn't what you're doing, this is the wrong place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

You simply put both of them in sequence in the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mpg -i vid2.mpg
```

This is according to the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5), FYI.

Comment: And if you ever have files that can't be concatenated, turn them first into file types that can.

Comment: A)I don't see it in the documentation B) That command is incomplete it needs an output file  C))Converting an flv I have to mpg, making a copy vid2.mpg and doing the command ffmpeg -i vid1.mpg -i vid2.mpg total.mpg   that produces the video same as an individual vid.

Comment: The resulting file for me was just the original file, not the other 3 I was trying to concatenate.